# How to know order settled or not in authorized.net

Tags: asp.net, authorize.net

I had implemented authorized.net for payment integration in my asp.net application. But I have to refund partial amount based on items are cancelled. But in authorized.net payment gateway make settlement in batch cycle. Before order settled we can not make partial refund amount from that transaction. So right now admin user have to wait for 24 hours for refund. but some time settle transaction happened after few hours as I said its depends on daily settle batch cycle.

Mu question is any technique or methods to know that order is settled or not in Authorized.net, so admin user not have to wait for 24 hours from transaction for partial refund.

My application in asp.net and I used AuthorizeNet dll for same.

Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: Authnet batches at the same time every day. If you ask them they'll tell you when it is. Than you can assume any transaction before that time is not settled. They also have a reporting API which can tell you this (but would be a lot more work to implement).